# How to create an 1h mp4 from a single photo?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I create an hour video of from a single photo? I tried `ffmpeg -i "photo.png" -framerate 10 -pattern_type  glob -t 00:05:00 -output video.mp4` but it did not seem to work as it created a video that shuts down after clicking Play.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think the bot is confused. I see only a single question, along with an attempt to resolve the question, which didn't work.

Comment: Add `-loop 1` argument. See [Creating a video from a single image for a specific duration in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891342/creating-a-video-from-a-single-image-for-a-specific-duration-in-ffmpeg).

Comment: `ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i "photo.png" -vf "format=yuv420p,loop=-1:1:0" -t 01:00:00 output.mp4`